# Can I use any manufacturer's Crossfire bridge cable?

Tags: graphics-card, crossfire

Basically, can I use any crossfire cable to connect two HD6850 cards or are there compatibility/version issues. Reference/source of info would be helpful.

**N.B.** *Please don't wander off into mobo requirements, packaging comments, included accessories (or not), etc.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any CrossfireX Bridge Interconnect cable will do the trick. I attached the one that came with my motherboard (ASRock) and the one that came with my cards (XFX) and both worked.